# Есть ли разница между GCC(g++) и Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

Есть пару вопросов от начинающего.

1. Если программа корректно компилируется в VS, будет ли она корректно компилироваться в g++(GCC)? В make?
2. Если программа корректно компилируется в VS на Windows 10, будет ли она корректно компилироваться на Linux?
3. Есть ли возможность проверить будет ли программа компилироваться в Linux и в g++(GCC)?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103852/discussion-on-question-by-------gccg--visual-s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Есть пару вопросов от начинающего.

Вопросов не пара, а три. :-)

> Если программа корректно компилируется в VS, будет ли она корректно
>   компилироваться в g++(GCC)?

Не факт, но при некоторых усилиях можно добиться, чтобы компилировалось и там и там.

> В make?

Сама утилита make ничего не компилирует, make это система для сборки, которая использует внешний компилятор.

> Если программа корректно компилируется в VS на Windows 10, будет ли
>   она корректно компилироваться на Linux?

Опять же смотря какой компилятор Вы примените в Linux. Кстати, компилироваться может и будет, а работать не будет, так как системные вызовы в Windows и Linux разные.

> Есть ли возможность проверить будет ли программа компилироваться в
>   Linux и в g++(GCC)?

Конечно, такая возможность есть. Ставите VS и GCC и проверяете.

UPD1:

Не обязательно ставить Linux, чтобы проверить компилируемость Вашей программы под GCC. Есть порты GCC под Windows.

UPD2:

В связи с захватывающим спором коллег о природе утилиты make я не поленился и поглядел, как в Википедии определяется эта утилита. Вот что там написано:

> make — утилита, автоматизирующая процесс преобразования файлов из
>   одной формы в другую. Чаще всего это компиляция исходного кода в
>   объектные файлы и последующая компоновка в исполняемые файлы или
>   библиотеки.
>
> Утилита использует специальные make-файлы, в которых указаны
>   зависимости файлов друг от друга и правила для их удовлетворения. На
>   основе информации о времени последнего изменения каждого файла make
>   определяет и запускает необходимые программы.

Comment: *"Есть порты GCC под Windows"* - [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Порт gcc под windows это [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php), а MSYS2 это проект, который воссоздаёт unix окружение (набор утилит) в windows, используя компилятор MinGW-w64 для сборки этих самых утилит.

Comment: @zed Я имел в виду, что скачать MinGW удобнее всего из пакетного менеджера MSYS2. Как ни странно, версия MinGW в MSYS2 новее той, которая в оффициальном установщике (у них там до сих пор 8.1).

Comment: 1. стоило бы отметить в ответе, что visual studio — это вовсе не компилятор. 2. не стоило бы вводить людей в заблуждение, называя **интерпретатор** *make*  «системой сборки».

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, если уж пошла такая пьянка, то не вводите в заблуждение людей и вы: *make — специализированный функциональный язык программирования со средой выполнения*.

Comment: aleksandr barakin, разве у Microsoft не свой собственный компилятор с ++ ?